# How to enable ngx_pagespeed on Dotdeb

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, pagespeed

please i have a question about ngx_pagespeed

When i install nginx-extras using dotdeb repos ngx_pagespeed is installed too or need make some thing more?

I added pagespéed on; in nginx.conf but it failed to start

Comment: Could you update your question to include the error message you're getting?

Comment: Thank you, i forgot to create ngx_pagespeed file cache, thank you !